# How do I access sprites from Carmageddon?

Tags: carmageddon

I want the all set of the Max Damage sprites from the [PratCam app](https://itunes.apple.com/il/app/id541105194?mt=8) (basically the same sprites there is in the game) for making a gif picture from it.

Are the sprites accessible in the game files somewhere, and if so, how can I copy them?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is looking for a place to find sprites, instead of asking about a game.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Well, so you can also relate that question as "How can I export the sprite of Max from the game itself" if its helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've tried so far and it's worked for me.
I've installed the game (the GOG version) and find all of the short videos of Max in this path:

```
C:\*where you have install the game*\Carmageddon\CARMA\DATA\64X48X8\PRATCAM\FRANK
```

All of the files are in FLI format, So you'll need the some media converter to change it from FLI to GIF (like VideoMach for example).